# Composed animations, sprites in iOS

Tags: ios, animation, sprite

let's say I want to display a customizable (2D, cartoon-like) character, where some properties e.g. eye color, hair style, clothing etc can be chosen from a predefined set of options. Now I want to animate the character. What's the best way to deal with the customization?

1) For example, I could make a sprite sheet for each combination of properties. That's not very memory efficient and not very flexible, but probably gives the best performance.

2) I could compose the character from various layers, where each property only affects one layer. Thus, I could make a sprite-sheet for the body, a collection of sprite-sheets for the eyes (one for each eye color) etc.

2a) In that case, I could merge the selected sprite-sheets in order to generate a single sprite-sheet containing the animation of the customized character.

2b) Alternatively, I could keep the sprite-sheets separate and try to animate them simultaneously as layers. I fear, that this might become a problem performance-wise.

3) I could try to modify the layers programmatically, e.g. use a sprite-sheet for the eyes as a mask and map some texture on it before merging it down to a single sprite-sheet. I would think this is a very flexible approach when it comes to simple properties like eye colors, but might become difficult for things like hair-style. I am aware that this depends much on the character and probably a general answer is difficult.

I assume that my problem is not new, so there is probably a standard approach to it.

Concerning the platform, I'm particularly interested in iOS and try to avoid OpenGL (well, I'm open-minded). Maybe there is a nice framework that can help me here?

Thanks!

Comment: Make one sprite sheet full of "parts" of your character. (chest, arm, legs, head, etc). Make them all white with a black border. Dynamically color them in your code by setting their color.

Answer (score 0):

You problably want to take a look on [how to create sprites](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3asprites) at [cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/).

Cocos2d comes with a set of tools that help you to animate single parts and offers abstractions to compose parts (like `CCBatchNode` or `CCNode`). Also, it comes with tools that helps you to pack sprites into sprite sheets (e.g [Texture Packer](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Creating_and_using_Sprite_Sheets_in_Cocos2D-X_with_Texture_Packer)) and develop levels (e.g [Level Helper](http://maniacdev.com/2011/07/tutorial-building-complete-games-with-spritehelper-and-levelhelper/)).

Cocos2d is an open source framework and it is widely used. You also have [cocos3d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/archives/tag/cocos3d) but I never used it :).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your working on, you might want to animate part/all of the animations outside in another tool, such as flash.  It is much easier to work with a visual environment.

Then there are tools that take swf files, and create sprite sheets that you would then animate in cocos2d.

That is a common game creation workflow.